# Change font of all Hebrew text

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, language, find-and-replace

I need to use different fonts for English and Hebrew in the same document. How can I change the font of all the Hebrew text, possibly using Find-and-Replace?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Change and Replace!

You should use STYLES. Styles is a very simple feature with great capabilities to little known to MS Word Users.

Click on Styles -> Than under Format choose your language. 
See the attached photo...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If Hebrew is not set up as a proofing language, set it up. Once Hebrew is set up as a proofing language (which may require a system restart [not just Word or Office restart] to become fully effective), you can use Find to select all the Hebrew text in your document.

Hit Ctrl+H.
Open the "More > >" option.
Go to Format > Language and select Hebrew.
Under "Find In," select "Main Document."

This should highlight all the Hebrew text in the document, and you should be able to manipulate the font settings for the highlighted text. You should not need to use different styles for English and Hebrew.